# getclicked list item from listview in android?

Tags: android

I use the below code to create listview without listactivity.I need to know how to get the selected list item from this.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     String[] myList = new String[] {"Hello","TEST","TEST","TEST4"};              
     ListView lv = new ListView(this);
     lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList));
     setContentView(lv);
}
```

Comment: this question has been answered dozens of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onItemClickListener`

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
});
```

http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29

Answer (score 0):

set listener on the list

```
lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

then implement it

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
   selection.setText(items[position]);
}
```